# Posting Data to asp.net core controller using angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I am new to Asp.net core. I am trying to make simple login page which connects to database. But for some reason I can't post username and password to controller.

Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
namespace WebApplication12.controllers
 {
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MysqlConnector test = new MysqlConnector();
        return View(test);
    }




    public string test_name { get; set; }
    public string test_role { get; set; }

    private MySqlConnection connectio;

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostData(string User, string Pass)
    {
        connect(User,Pass);
        MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand();
        query.Connection = connectio;
        query.CommandText = string.Format("Select * from users");

        MySqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();
        try
        {
            test_name = reader["user"].ToString(); //reader.getString(1);
            test_role = reader["role"].ToString();
            reader.Close();
            return Json(new {success=true , user=test_name});

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            test_name = err.ToString();
            test_role = err.ToString();
            reader.Close();
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }



    }


    private void connect(string user,string pass)
    {


        string ConnectionString =  string.Format("server=localhost ;database=xdata; uid={0} ; pwd={1}",user,pass);

        connectio = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connectio.Open();



    }
}
```

login.html

```
 <p><input ng-model="username" value="Username"/></p>
 <p><input ng-model="password" value="Password"/></p>
<p><button type="button" ng-click="submit(username,password)">Click to Submit</button></p>
```

angular code

```
 $http.post('/HomeController/PostData/', {
        'User': user,
        'Pass': pass

    })

    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.something = data;
        console.log(data);

    }).error(function (response) {

        alert("Fail");

    });
```

When I click the button, on the console, it shows the entire html. Apparently there is an error while posting. Thanks in advance. ( error at "HomeController/PostData/ (?)   )

Comment: Unless you have changed it from the default, isn't the route usually `api/<controller>/<action>`? If so, the URL should be `api/Home/PostData/`.

Comment: my route is like this  routes.MapRoute("default", "{*catchall}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has to be changed to address two issues.

Issue 1: Routing

As Rani Radcliff pointed out the URL in `$http.post` has to be changed to `'/Home/PostData';` otherwise a 404 status code will be received. The default route for a Method "`fooMethod`" in a controller "`fooController`" is "`/foo/fooMethod`".

Issue 2: Read model from body

Introduce a model class and annotate the action with `[FromBody]`

```
public class LoginModel {
    public string User {get; set;}
    public string Pass {get; set;}
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostData([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Issue 3: Prefer HTTP status codes to signal success or failure

In your sample the JSON response includes a boolean `success` property. According to the principles of a RESTful API it is better to us HTTP status codes. In ASP.NET Core you can use specific helper functions of the Controller-Base-Class, e.g. instead of return JsonResult you can use

```
return Ok(); 
return Ok(someObject); // someObject will be converted to JSON
```

or

```
return Unauthorized();
```

Comment: I did the first and it worked but for the second how i should define the User and Pass in $http.post ?  I mean when I am posting the user and pass from angularjs, will it automatically see these parameter in the LoginModel. sorry for my english if I couldn't explain it well.

Comment: @risefire You should not need to modify the post. The asp.net core framework matches the names of the JSON properties to the properties of the C# class.

Comment: It seems the post is working but now the controller returns the entire cshtml page to "data" (.success(function(data)). Additionally, I am showing the html page on the cshtml using ng-view. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @risefile - I added some hints about returning HTTP Status codes. Regarding the returned HTML-data I wonder which HTML this should be. Is this the ASP.NET Core Error Page (Exception happened) or a redirect to a login page (caused by a Authorize-Annotation)? Because in your sample code there is no view addressed in the controller code.

Comment: -  [What "data" shows](https://s32.postimg.org/nf24flat1/Untitled.png) After clicking the button, the post status says 200 (successful) but instead of returning what I want from controller, this shows up.

Comment: @risefire - I would say this is a "success indicator". I cannot tell it exactly because now code is executed that is not part of your original post. The PostData controller method is executed with return code 200 (sucess). Therefore the promise in the angular controller is fullfilled (success-method executed). Now I assume the ng-view is triggered and fetches the HTML data from RouteOne - that is another method. If you have questions on this behaviour then you should better create another question. I hope my input was helpful and answered your original post.

Answer (score 3):

Take the word "Controller" out.  Try changing your code to:

```
 $http.post('/Home/PostData/', {
    'User': user,
    'Pass': pass

})

.success(function (data) {
    $scope.something = data;
    console.log(data);

}).error(function (response) {

    alert("Fail");

});
```